# JQuery in parent page not detecting id element in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dynamic id element "deleteSite" (in a partial view) clicking on which shall remove the Site from a table. When I click on it, the jquery function(in the parent page) is not getting called except for the first element. Please help me to see what is going wrong here.

The page is loaded normally intially,but via ajax during paging

Here's my partial view

```
@model IPagedList<MvcSIMS.Models.Site>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: auto;">SlNo</th>
                    <th>SiteName</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                    
                @foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@(item.Index + ((Model.PageNumber - 1) * Model.PageSize) + 1)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.SITENAME)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.REMARKS)</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.Data.ID })" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a id="deleteSite" href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Data.ID })"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }                    
            </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is what my jquery is doing -

```
 $(function () {

 //Delete function
        $("#deleteSite").click(function () {
            alert("hai");
            return false;
  })
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because ids **must be unique** so jQuery will return only one. Consider using a class to identifying your button, such as:

```
class="delete-site"
```

Then change your jQuery to be (we also delegate the event so there's only ever one event for n amount of items, this means that also items added later via AJAX will still be registered for this event):

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-site", function () {
    alert("hai");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a loop

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
```

inside which you do this

```
 <a id="deleteSite" href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Data.ID })"
```

which means that "deleteSite" will appear as many times as there are items in your model. This is not valid as each id must be unique within the page / sub page.

you could try using a class or data-attribute do this instead.

```
<a class="deleteSite" href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Data.ID })"
```

and then replace the script with

```
$('.delete-site').on("click", function () {
  alert("hai");
  return false;
});
```